# MYSQL: Handling Multiple LEFT JOINS

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have a query with one `LEFT JOIN` that works fine.  When I add a second `LEFT JOIN` to a table with multiple records per field in the first table, however, I am getting the product of the results in the two tables ie books x publishers returned.  How can I prevent this from happening?

```
 SELECT a.*,b.*,p.*, group_concat(b.id as `bids`) 
    FROM authors `a`
    LEFT JOIN books `b`
    ON b.authorid = a.id 
    LEFT JOIN publishers `p` 
    on p.authorid = a.id 
    GROUP by a.id
```

**EDIT:**

Figured it out.  The way to do this is to use subqueries as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135):

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.account_balance
     , g.grocery_visits
     , f.fishmarket_visits
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, count(*) AS grocery_visits
   FROM   grocery
   GROUP  BY user_id
   ) g ON g.user_id = u.id
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, count(*) AS fishmarket_visits
   FROM   fishmarket
   GROUP  BY user_id
   ) f ON f.user_id = u.id
ORDER  BY u.id;
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: I updated the question...Any ideas?

Comment: your question is not clear ... please add  a proper data sample and the expected  result ..

Answer (score 0):

If you do multiple LEFT Joins, your query will return a cartesian product of the results.  To avoid this and get only one copy of fields you desire,  do a subquery for each table you wish to join as below.  Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.account_balance
     , g.grocery_visits
     , f.fishmarket_visits
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, count(*) AS grocery_visits
   FROM   grocery
   GROUP  BY user_id
   ) g ON g.user_id = u.id
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, count(*) AS fishmarket_visits
   FROM   fishmarket
   GROUP  BY user_id
   ) f ON f.user_id = u.id
ORDER  BY u.id;
```